How to build a chart with multiple dimensions when the same field changes over time?
Consider the following sample table:
  day  |  payment_id  |  status
---------------------------------
 Jan 1 |      1       | processing
 Jan 1 |      2       | processing
 Jan 2 |      1       | completed
 Jan 2 |      2       | processing


As you can see, it consists of the day, payment_id, and status. Each payment can appear on multiple days with different statuses (e.g., payment 1 in the table below has different statuses on two different days).
What I need to do is to build a table in Looker Studio (Google Data Studio), which would be a simple stacked bar chart displaying the number of payments with different status over time. It's easy to do this for each day, or for each week, but the problem arises when I need to create a chart where you would be able to switch between different time periods (days, weeks, months, etc.)
For example, for a daily chart, Jan 1 would show 2 payments with status processing, while Jan 2 would show 1 payment with status processing and 1 payment with status completed.
For a weekly chart, on the other hand, it would just show 1 payment with status processing and 1 payments with status completed for this whole week.
So it looks like for a weekly chart, I would need to take the latest status for each payment. Something like max_by function, but it doesn't exist in looker studio.
Is it possible to create such a chart with multiple dimensions (days, weeks, months)? If so, how do I correctly aggregate the data?

So if you want a weekly chart you want the most recent status value of that week for each payment_id?

@Korean_Of_the_Mountain That's correct.

So to get the most recent row for a week in a table broken up by day is that you need to use a window function to rank/sort the rows for each week + payment_id. Which means you'll need a PDT that does this first and then create a explore on that PDT. Or have a pipeline/process that maintains a table with window function already applied.

My problem is not with getting the most recent row for a week, but with building a chart that would work with both daily and weekly (and monthly, yearly) time periods

Are you trying to have a chart that somehow does all time period at same time or just make it easier for user to choose a time period and dynamically update chart?

I'd like a chart that allows to drill down with time periods. So that I could change the view from monthly to weekly, etc.

in that case, i'd create a parameter with time interval options a user can choose. Then i guess create a dimension that truncates the date field for that time interval selection. If you reference that dimension in your Explore and viz, then  it'll dynamically update based on parameter value change

Not sure if I understood correctly, but I ended up creating a dataset with all the different period types (month, week, day, etc.), and then creating a control where a user would be able to select the necessary period type. That should work well enough for me. Thanks!

Based on the sample table in OP:
You can create a parameter for user to select date interval
parameter: date_interval_param {
    allowed_value: {
      label: "Day"
      value: "day"
    }
    allowed_value: {
      label: "Week"
      value: "week"
    }
    allowed_value: {
      label: "Month"
      value: "month"
    }
    allowed_value: {
      label: "Quarter"
      value: "quarter"
    }
    allowed_value: {
      label: "Year"
      value: "year"
    }
  }


Then have a dimension that updates based on that parameter value and use the existing Looker timeframe options
dimension_group: day {
   type: time
   sql: cast(${TABLE}.day as timestamp) ;;  ## field based on sample table in OP
}

dimension: date_interval_field_dash {
    sql:

    {% if date_interval_param._is_filtered %}
      {% if date_interval_param._parameter_value == "'year'" %}
        ${day_year}
      {% elsif date_interval_param._parameter_value == "'quarter'" %}
        ${day_quarter}
      {% elsif date_interval_param._parameter_value == "'month'" %}
        ${day_month}
      {% elsif date_interval_param._parameter_value == "'week'" %}
        ${day_week}
      {% elsif date_interval_param._parameter_value == "'day'" %}
        ${day_date}
      {% endif %}
    {% else %}
    YOU HAVE TO SELECT "DATE INTERVAL OPTIONS" FILTER
    {% endif %}
    ;;
  }

And if you reference date_interval_field_dash as the dimension in your Explore viz, it'll update based on the interval selected by user.
This is less redundant and more flexible than trying to maintain a table that contains the pre-aggregated interval options
